# join digits by removing special characters

Tags: regex

I can use some basic regular expression in python to extract digits. But what I am trying to achive is to concat all the digits separated by any chars except space.

```
>>> ss = ["apple-12.34 ba33na fanc-14.23yapple+45+67.56",
          'hello X42 I\'m a Y-32.35 string Z30',
          'he33llo 42 I\'m a 32 string -30',
          'h3110 23 cat 444.4 rabbit 11 2 dog',
          "hello 12 hi 89"]                                                     
>>> for s in ss:
...     print re.findall("\d+", s)   

['12', '34', '33', '14', '23', '45', '67', '56']
['42', '32', '35', '30']
['33', '42', '32', '30']
['3110', '23', '444', '4', '11', '2']
['12', '89']
```

Expected Results:

```
['1234', '33', '1423456756']
['42', '3235', '30']
['33', '42', '32', '30']
['3110', '23', '4444', '11', '2']
['12', '89']
```

Comment: Another question is why does `fanc-14.23yapple+45+67.56` yield [`1423`, `456756`] and not `[1423456756]`.

Comment: Both comments are correct. Updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this line a try:

```
...your for loop:
    print re.findall("\d+", re.sub(r'(?<=\d)[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+(?=\d)','',s))
```

test with your example, it output:

```
In [4]: for s in ss:
    print re.findall("\d+", re.sub(r'(?<=\d)[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+(?=\d)','',s))
   ...:     
['1234', '33', '1423', '456756']
['42', '3235', '30']
['33', '42', '32', '30']
['3110', '23', '4444', '11', '2']
['12', '89']
```

### Update since OP changed requirement

The idea is remove those non-empty chars between digits, then extract with `\d+`

```
In [4]: for s in ss:
    print re.findall("\d+", re.sub(r'(?<=\d)[^\s\d]+(?=\d)','',s))
   ...:     
['1234', '33', '1423456756']
['42', '3235', '30']
['33', '42', '32', '30']
['3110', '23', '4444', '11', '2']
['12', '89']
```

Comment: Your answer looks good and is the first one, so OP fixed the question, please edit it! I will give you a +1

Answer (score 2):

replace every character other than digit and white space in the string and then split.

```
>>> import re
>>> line = 'apple-12.34 ba33na fanc-14.23yapple+45+67.56'
>>> list_of_numbers = re.replace('[^\d\s]', '', line).split()
>>> print list_of_numbers
['1234', '33', '1423456756']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
re.findall("\d+", re.sub(r"(?<=\d)[^\s\d]*(?=\d)", "", s))
```

See [this demo](http://ideone.com/djHvTm)

With `(?<=\d)[^\s\d]*(?=\d)`, you will remove any number of characters other than whitespace and digits between two digits. Then, you will be able to extract the remaining digit sequences using a mere `\d+` pattern.

Result:

```
['1234', '33', '1423456756']
['42', '3235', '30']
['33', '42', '32', '30']
['3110', '23', '4444', '11', '2']
['12', '89']
```